# Peculiar behaviour in play 1.2.4 while using Bootstrap javascript files

Tags: jquery, playframework, twitter-bootstrap, playframework-1.x

I am using three javascript files: `bootstrap.js`,`jquery.js`,`bootstrap-dropdown.js`.I have implemented a header in every html page in my project that has a dropdown and in one html page I have implemented a modal class. Now whenever I import `bootstrap.js` before `jquery.js` the dropdown works but the modal class doesn't and when I do the reverse the modal works but the dropdown does not.

The list of js files in sequence i have used:

```
<script src="@{'/public/javascripts/bootstrap.js'}" type="text/javascript" charset="${_response_encoding}"></script>
<script src="@{'/public/javascripts/jquery.js'}" type="text/javascript" charset="${_response_encoding}"></script>

<script src="@{'/public/javascripts/sessvars.js'}" type="text/javascript" charset="${_response_encoding}"></script>

<script src="@{'/public/javascripts/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js'}" type="text/javascript" charset="${_response_encoding}"></script>
<script src="@{'/public/javascripts/sessvars.js'}" type="text/javascript" charset="${_response_encoding}"></script>
<script src="@{'/public/javascripts/bootstrap-dropdown.js'}" type="text/javascript" charset="${_response_encoding}"></script>
```

Comment: Check if jquery UI doesn't conflict with bootstrap. Remove doubled `sessvars.js`, Use your browser's developer's tools (ie. FireBug for FireFox) and go to the Console to find JavaScript errors.

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap depends on jquery so you need to declare jquery script before bootstrap

Dropdown code is normally included into bootstrap.js so you don't need both declarations.

If you still have issues, open you browser error console to see what's going wrong